# Phase Shifter: why is simple RC circuit's output 0 when phase is 90 deg?

Tags: ac, filter, voltage-divider, phase

I am rereading an electronics book (Fundamentals of Electric Circuits; Alexander) that says that the circuits

[image: Lagging-Output RC Phase Shifter] or [image: Leading-Output RC Phase Shifter]

have the total impedance

> **Z** = R + jXc

and that the phase shift is given by

> theta = arctan(Xc/R)

where **Xc = -1/wC**

It then says:

> *We should keep in mind that [these] simple RC circuits ... also
>   act as voltage dividers. Therefore, as the phase shift θ approaches
>   90◦ , the output voltage Vo approaches zero.*

I can see that as theta -> pi/2, Xc/R goes to infinity, meaning that C or R must be very small.  In the second example, if Xc is so much larger than R, then I can see that eventually all the voltage will be across it and none at Vo.  (Is that what he means by voltage divider?) However, in the first example, if C is very small then Xc is very large, and doesn't that mean that all the voltage will be across it and Vo will approach Vi?  Or is C so small that it acts like a short?  If the latter is the case, then why isn't C a short in the second example and all the voltage across R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start by pointing out that circuit 1 is the same as circuit 2 and that measuring an output across the resistor will look like a high pass filter whereas measuring it across the capacitor will look like a low pass filter. The filter will have a transitional point (or 3 dB point or half power point) at: -

f = \$\dfrac{1}{2\pi RC}\$

If you measure across the resistor and the capacitor at this transitional frequency you'll see that the RMS voltage is the same at: -

\$\dfrac{V_{IN}}{\sqrt2}\$

You'll also find that |Xc| = R at this frequency and that the phase shift of the signal across the resistor is exactly 90 degrees from the voltage across the capacitor. If you messed around a bit more you will find that this is always the situation because the current through both components is the same. If current is the same then the voltage across C always lags the voltage across R by 90 degrees.

It's also true that at very high frequencies Xc is very much smaller than R so the voltage across R closely resembles the input voltage whereas the voltage across C will be very small. At very low frequencies the opposite is true - the voltage across C is very similar to the voltage on the input and the voltage across R is tiny.

Only at these extremes will the phase shift produce close to 90 degrees and that will be seen across the component that has the lowest impedance.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'm a little confused, though.  You say in the third paragraph that if |Xc|=R, then the phase shift between the R and C is 90.  But shouldn't it be 45 degrees?  Or is the arctan equation for something else?  And the book says that Vo goes to 0 as the phase shift approaches 90.  It just doesn't sit well with me that both configurations can have an output of 0 at 90 degrees, when the complete voltage in each case will be across different elements.

Comment: With identical current through both series components, the voltage across R will be 90 degrees distant from the voltage across the capacitor. This is true at any frequency of current but, I specifically mentioned when |Xc| = R because it's most easily observable at this point.

Comment: The last part of your question - yes, it may not sit well but it's true. I think if you had an o-scope and messed around a bit it would start to gel. The output is 90 degrees but infinitely small! - Roll back to 89.5 degrees and you have a small output - you could see this on an o-scope.

Comment: Yeah, I need some time to simulate this before I can tell if this is the answer.  However, definitely +1 for all the help.  Thanks.

Comment: Good idea to simulate

Answer (score 0):

Your first circuit is a low pass filter.  DC up to the corner frequency (fc =1/(2*pi*R*C)) are passed through. The second is a high pass filter, all frequencies above the corner (same fc) are passed.  OK, the details are more involved.  I think the best thing is to get a 'scope and  function generator and see what happens.  Next best is maybe to play with LTspice.  Then go do the math again.

Comment: I know that these are filters.  I'm not asking about the low/high pass quality.  I'm focusing on the phase shifting characteristic.  In that case, one can assume that Vi has a constant frequency, and Vo should be the same frequency as Vi but with a phase shift and an attenuated amplitude.  In this question, I'm mostly asking about the latter.

Comment: @MrUser, OK the best way I know to understand some of this stuff is to see it in action.  (A 'scope and function generator)  One thing that is hard to see from the equations, at least for me, is that the phase shift is apparent much before you see any change in amplitude.